# Php - Subtracting days from gmdate() date

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

I would like to subtract 180 days from a GMDATE() (for UTC purposes) I have in a PHP script. I have just looked on SO but hardly anybody is using gmdate().

This is what I have:

```
$from_date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Is there a simple way to subtract X amount of days from this, without using a different function completely? Or should I be doing it another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DateTime. Much better for working with dates especially when working with timezones.

```
$datetime = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$datetime->modify('-180 days');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

**Reference**

- [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [DateTimeZone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

Comment: Is that formatted in UTC as standard, regardless of my server's timezone?

Comment: I updated my code to make sure this was always the case without affecting other DateTime code.

Answer (score 1):

Formatted in UTC should be like;

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$datetime = new DateTime('NOW', $timezone);
$datetime->modify('-180 days');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Datetime: [PHP DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

> `public __construct ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )`

Timezone: [PHP DateTimeZone class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

> `public __construct ( string $timezone )`

Answer (score 0):

gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 15552000)